# Problem with multi-stage Dockerfile (Python - venv)

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to create a Python webapp docker image using multi-stage, to shrink the image size... right now it's around 300mb... it's also using virtual enviroment.

The docker image builds and runs fine up untill the point I need to add multi-stage so I know something is going wrong after that.... Could you help me out identifying what's wrong?

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine AS origin
RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN apk --no-cache add py3-pip build-base
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv venv
RUN source venv/bin/activate
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
## Works fine until this point ""

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=origin /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH" VIRTUAL_ENV="/opt/venv"
COPY . /opt/app/
CMD [ "file.py" ]
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

Without the VENV it looks something like this (still throwing error "sh: python: not found"):

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine AS origin
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN apk --no-cache add py3-pip build-base
RUN pip install -U pip
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=origin /opt/app .
CMD sh -c 'python file.py'
```

Comment: What happens at the point where it starts going wrong? And why use a virtualenv in what's already an isolated environment?

Comment: I get a "python docker standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error". Well, the company I'm applying for asked for a virtual enviroment to run the app... I also think it's uselss inside a container....

Comment: A docker container is an isolated environment on its own. Usually it does not bring any benefits to create a virtual environment inside.

Comment: Please provide the output of `docker inspect alpine:latest` and `docker info`.

Comment: So, without a venv, I'm doing this now but still getting the error "sh: python: not found" 

FROM python:3.8.3-alpine AS origin
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN apk --no-cache add py3-pip build-base
RUN pip install -U pip
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=origin /opt/app .
CMD sh -c 'python file.py'

Comment: I have edited the first post with the code removing the VENV... still giving me an error... It must be something really silly....

Answer (score 3):

You still need `pyhton` in your runtime container, since you changed your last image to just `alpine` it wouldn't work. Just a tip, combine your `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` under one of them, there is generally no need for having two of them. Try to use only `ENTRYPOINT` since you can pass `CMD` easily in runtime for example to activate debug mode more easily.

EDIT: Please stay away from alpine for python apps as [you can get some weird issues about it](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/). You can use "*python_version*-slim-buster" images, they are small enough.

Comment: Isn't the python runtime copied from the builder image? I think I'm messing up with the directories, when trying to copy from the builder image to the runtime and then trying to execute.... I'm not really an expert on muli-stage builds... I was able to build an Ubuntu image just fine, but the size is bad and I need to push this over to Git...

Comment: `python:3.8.3-alpine` image is small enough for final image. Since you don't install python to your venv there is just system link to real python. Your ubuntu image works because it contains python most likely.

Comment: Without multi-stage, I was able to build an image from debian buster-slim and it's around 140mb. It's not perfect, but it's better than the 300mb I was getting. I also removed the virtual enviroment since it's a pain to deal with... Do you have any suggestions to shrink the image even more, using multi-stage? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not working with python for a long time and I totally forgot alpine is not a right runtime for python. I suggest you to use venv with multi-stage with debian-buster-slim as both runtime and builder. This will be smallest and most stable as you get.